# Bounding lines by the polygon underneath

Tags: r, tmap

I am new to the `{tmap}` package, and I am having difficulty creating a proper road map. Here is my code (not immediately runnable, because I have an exported OpenStreetMap `.osm` file on disk).

```r
# Load OpenStreetMap (OSM) polygon data of the Holden area from disk
holden_bbox_shapes = sf::read_sf('./localdata/holden.osm', 'multipolygons')

# Load OSM line data from disk. These are almost all roads.
holden_lines = sf::read_sf('holden.osm', 'lines')

# Get just the administrative town of holden
holden_town_polygon = dplyr::filter(holden_bbox_shapes, name == 'Holden')

tm_shape(holden_town_polygon) +
tm_fill() +
tm_shape(holden_lines) +
tm_lines()
```

The image result is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KBLAy.jpg), in which the roads go beyond the visible region of `holden_town_polygon`, but within what I would imagine is the boundary box of the `holden_town_polygon` object. I don't know why that happens nor how to configure it. I tried finagling with the `bbox` parameter in all `tm_*` functions, but nothing would change the result.

I would like to see only the part of the roads within the shaded polygon. What would be the proper way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get use `st_intersection` from the `sf` package.

It would look something like this:

```
library(sf)

inside_lines <- st_intersection(holden_lines, holden_town_polygon)

tm_shape(holden_town_polygon) +
tm_fill() +
tm_shape(inside_lines) +
tm_lines()
```